# Insert data from Oracle 18 to SQL Server 2016 over dblink (dg4msql)

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

We have a problem with inserting data from Oracle 18 to SQL Server 2016 over dblink (dg4msql).

ENV:

- ORACLE Version 18.4.0.0.0 + Oracle Database Gateway for MS SQL Server 18.0.0.0.0 on separate hosts
- SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.4001.0)

For mapping data type I use:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/data-type-mapping-for-oracle-publishers?view=sql-server-2016

In ORACLE GW set parameters:

```
HS_LANGUAGE=RUSSIAN_RUSSIA.CL8MSWIN1251
HS_FDS_RECOVERY_ACCOUNT=RECOVER
HS_FDS_RECOVERY_PWD=RECOVER
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO=X.X.X.X:1433//BUFFER1
HS_NLS_DATE_FORMAT="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"
HS_NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER=".,"
```

Oracle client(sqlplus):

```
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251
NLS_DATE_FORMAT="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=".,"
```

In Oracle we have global temporary table

```
desc TBL_KPI_2G_TEMP

Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
d                                                  DATE
reg                                                VARCHAR2(500)
LAC                                                NUMBER
CI                                                 NUMBER
Cell                                               VARCHAR2(500)
traf_sp                                            NUMBER
cssr                                               NUMBER
bcr                                                NUMBER
dcr                                                NUMBER
hr_usage                                           NUMBER
trf_bh                                             NUMBER
trf_bh_30_avg                                      NUMBER
trf_bh_30_max                                      NUMBER
trf_bh_30_perc_92                                  NUMBER
trf_ul_mb                                          NUMBER
trf_dl_mb                                          NUMBER
tbf_sr                                             NUMBER
tbf_dr                                             NUMBER
tbf_br                                             NUMBER
avail                                              NUMBER
ho_sr                                              NUMBER
```

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    table_name, column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length, numeric_precision
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS@MS_DBLINK
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'TBL_KPI_2G'; 

TABLE_NAME    COLUMN_NAME      DATA_TYPE    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH    NUMERIC_PRECISION
TBL_KPI_2G    id                 int                10
TBL_KPI_2G    d                  datetime        
TBL_KPI_2G    reg                varchar            500    
TBL_KPI_2G    LAC                float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    CI                 float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    Cell               varchar            500    
TBL_KPI_2G    traf_sp            float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    cssr               float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    bcr                float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    dcr                float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    hr_usage           float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    trf_bh             float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    trf_bh_30_avg      float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    trf_bh_30_max      float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    trf_bh_30_perc_92  float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    trf_ul_mb          float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    trf_dl_mb          float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    tbf_sr             float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    tbf_dr             float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    tbf_br             float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    avail              float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    ho_sr              float                                        53
TBL_KPI_2G    d2                 date        
TBL_KPI_2G    d3                 datetime2        
TBL_KPI_2G    beg                varchar            20    
TBL_KPI_2G    ends               varchar            20    
TBL_KPI_2G    mid1               varchar            20    
TBL_KPI_2G    mid2               varchar            20
```

First problem (inversion of columns):

```
insert into TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK ("beg", "mid1", "mid2", "ends") 
select 
 '1','2','3','4' 
from TBL_KPI_2G_TEMP;  

1 rows created. 

SQL> commit; 

Commit complete. 

SQL> select "beg","mid1","mid2","ends"from TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK; 

beg 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
mid1 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
mid2 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
ends 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
4
3
2
1
```

--------------------second problem(Invalid character value)-----------

```
     SQL> insert into TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK("d","Cell","trf_ul_mb","reg","d3") select'2020-10-15 21:14:09','ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',5.6,'ffff','2020-10-15 21:14:09' from dual;                
                
1 row created.                
                
SQL> insert into TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK("d","Cell","trf_ul_mb","reg","d3") select'2020-10-15 21:14:09','ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',5.6,'ffff','2020-10-15 21:14:09' from dual;                
                
1 row created.                
                
SQL> commit;                
                
Commit complete.                
                
SQL> insert into TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK("d","Cell","trf_ul_mb","reg","d3") select'2020-10-15 21:14:09','ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',5.6,'ffff','2020-10-15 21:14:09' from dual;                
insert into TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK("d","Cell","trf_ul_mb","reg","d3") select'2020-10-15 21:14:09','ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',5.6,'ffff','2020-10-15 21:14:09' from dual                
                       *                
ERROR at line 1:                
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qerrdmliFlushRows], [28500],                
[ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this                
message:                
[Oracle][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver]Invalid character value. Error in                
parameter 4. {22018}                
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from MS_DBLINK                
], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [] 


select "d","Cell","trf_ul_mb","reg","d3" from TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK;


d                              Cell                            trf_ul_mb reg                            d3
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
2020-10-15 21:14:09             B    ?H    ??  ???  @?  ########## ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ             2020-10-15 21:14:09
                                  ??U             ?F     @

2020-10-15 21:14:09             B    ?H    ??  ???  @?  ########## ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ             2020-10-15 21:14:09
                                  H?U             ?F     @
```

I do not understand what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is not a problem. It shows one row of output. The row contains four fields that are pretty wide and fold over four lines of screen output, but it is still one row. There are commands to format fields to shorter strings, but the table data is just fine.

About your second problem: why not use the more standard approach like:

```
insert into TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK
   (d, Cell, trf_ul_mb, reg, d3)
values
   ('2020-10-15 21:14:09', 
    'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
    5.6,
    'ffff',
    '2020-10-15 21:14:09');
```

Formatting the query over more lines helps in understanding.

Quotes around field names avoid but also cause case problems. Normally, you don't need those quotes.

FROM DUAL was not needed.

---

About problem 1: are you sure you inserted 1 row of four fields? It looks like you inserted 4 rows of 1 field. Reason of misunderstanding is not using `values(...)` .

Also, in SQL, rows are not stored 'ordered'. You can explicitly specify `ORDER BY`  in your select query for viewing your table.

Try:

```
SELECT "beg" FROM TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK;
```

This will problably show 4 records.

Comment: this is a problem because the order of the inserted information is changed
It was
'1', '2', '3', '4'
but we get
'4', '3', '2', '1'
the order of the requested fields ("beg", "mid1", "mid2", "ends") does not change, you are not careful!

Comment: There is no question mark in your "question", but you wrote "I do not understand", so I answer at a basic level. Why not just first simplify your insert queries? In the 1st problem, you should also remove quotes from field names, and use `values(...)` instead of `select...from...`, and format the entire query in a more pretty-print way. Then retry, understand more, and formulate a more concrete question.

Comment: SQL> SELECT "beg" FROM TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK;

beg
--------------------
4

Comment: SELECT "beg" FROM TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK; show only one record.

Answer (score 0):

i think you not understand

```
SQL> delete from TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK;
commit;

1 row deleted.

SQL>
Commit complete.

SQL> SQL> SQL>
SQL>
SQL> select '1' "beg",'2' "mid1" ,'3' "mid2",'4' "ends" from dual;

beg                  mid1                 mid2                 ends
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1                    2                    3                    4

SQL> insert into TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK ("beg", "mid1", "mid2", "ends")
  2  select '1' "beg",'2' "mid1" ,'3' "mid2",'4' "ends" from dual;

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>  select "beg", "mid1", "mid2", "ends" from  TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK;

beg                  mid1                 mid2                 ends
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
4                    3                    2                    1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trtiq.jpg)

double quotes are used when fields are case sensitive
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gcda.jpg)

insert one values work fine, but i need insert data from table and have a problem "Heterogeneous Services datatype mapping error"

```
    delete from TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK;

1 row deleted.

SQL>  insert into TBL_KPI_2G_TEMP ("d", "Cell", "trf_ul_mb", "reg", "d3") values
   ('2020-10-15 21:14:09',
    'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
    5.6,
    'ffff',
    '2020-10-15 21:14:09');   2    3    4    5    6

1 row created.

SQL>  insert into TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK("d", "Cell", "trf_ul_mb", "reg", "d3") select "d", "Cell", "trf_ul_mb", "reg", "d3" from TBL_KPI_2G_TEMP;
 insert into TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK("d", "Cell", "trf_ul_mb", "reg", "d3") select "d", "Cell", "trf_ul_mb", "reg", "d3" from TBL_KPI_2G_TEMP
                                                                                                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qerrdmliFlushRows], [28527], [ORA-28527: Heterogeneous Services datatype mapping error
ORA-02063: preceding line from MS_DBLINK
], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []


SQL> insert into TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK
   ("d", "Cell", "trf_ul_mb", "reg", "d3")
values
   ('2020-10-15 21:14:09',
    'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
    5.6,
    'ffff',
    '2020-10-15 21:14:09');  2    3    4    5    6    7    8

1 row created.

SQL> select "d", "Cell", "trf_ul_mb", "reg", "d3" from TBL_KPI_2G@MS_DBLINK;

d                    Cell                 trf_ul_mb reg                  d3
-------------------- -------------------- --------- -------------------- --------------------
2020-10-15 21:14:09  ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ          5.60 ffff                 2020-10-15 21:14:09
```

Comment: Is this an answer, or a reformulation of your problem? You had two problems, but to me it was not clear what the problem was because I gave you some hints and you did not use those. If you still need help, please get rid of quotes in the SQL queries, simplify things, try what I suggested, and formulate a real question.

Comment: QUESTION, why MS SQL reverses the inserted data?

Comment: i can't get rid of the quotes because the columns have lowercase names